# How to split Regex Pattern based on condition

Tags: java, regex, annotations

I want to match all the values present in the text having units nm or µm. Below is the regex pattern which matches 20 nm or 20nm

```
public Pattern Value = Pattern.compile("\\d*\\.?\\d*(\\s?[nNμµ][mM])");
```

How can i program it to match only the value if it is having units nm or µm

Comment: change `[nNμµ][mM]` to `[nµ][mM]`? Or I do not understand you...

Comment: I think he wants the output to be 20, rather than 20nm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a capturing group to catch the value:

```
public Pattern Value = Pattern.compile("(\\d*\\.?\\d*)(?:\\s?[nNμµ][mM])");
```

The value here would be contained in the 1st group.

You could also use [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
public Pattern Value = Pattern.compile("\\d*\\.?\\d*(?=\\s?[nNμµ][mM])");
```

Here you would only match the value.

Answer (score 0):

Use [lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
public Pattern Value = Pattern.compile("(?i)\\d+\\.?\\d*(?=\\s*[nµ]m)");
```

Also, make at least one of the digits mandatory.